# Android rtl support without reload Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, right-to-left

Is it possible to turn rtl support on without reload activity. I am using detach and attach fragments and properties are translated, but rtl direction of elements works only if I reload or `recreate()` my activity. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Probably not. Layout direction is considered a configuration change, and there may be resources qualified for specific layout directions, so it's better to let the system go through that process as normal. You could try to workaround it with `View.setLayoutDIrection()`, but it might not be quite right.

Comment: @TeodorKelov Did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`View.setLayoutDirection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutDirection(int)) to manually set a layout direction. Be aware the layout direction is considered a configuration change and there may be resources qualified based on layout direction, and it's better to let the system go through its normal process in order to pick up these resources.